# extending a holomorphic function outside the unit disc?

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f$ is analytic on the open unit disc and $|f^{(k)}(0)| \leq k^4C^k$ for all $k$. Why can $f$ be extended to a holomorphic function on $\mathbb{C}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint** Let

$$g(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{f^k(0)}{k!}x^k \,.$$

What is the radius of convergence of this Power series? And why does this solve your problem?

Comment: Yup that is more or less what I argued. Said it works by using weierstrass m test!